# appcompat v7 attribute values are not found. Support library(21) status is "installed"

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

min sdk version of app: 11 target:14

support library : 21
support repository : 11

compiled using sdk 4.0

It looks like because of this my R is also not resolved as Project cannot be built. So, I cannot proceed with the project.

console consists of many error messages of this kind..

```
C:\Users\e-class\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'
```

Please help me how to solve those values

Comment: You have to compile with api 21

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Is it possible that I could compile with api 21 and be compatible with api 14 by changing my min sdk to 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to use support library v21 you will have to set your apps target sdk to 21. Support library relies on some xml attributes that have been added in api level 21 and won't be able to compile without them.

Comment: how to add api level 14 for 4.0 compatibility

Comment: I intend to work on 4.0 so that I could reach more devices. Is there any way that I could add support library 14

Comment: In general you should set target sdk to the latest. Whit min sdk version you actually restrict what is the lowest version that you will support. So if you set your min sdk version to 14 users will be able to install your app on devices with android 4.0.

Comment: Its like I have neglected this problem early on and developed for api 21

Comment: Its like I have neglected this problem early on and developed for api 21.
But all the code could support previous versions. But changing min sdk does not work..  I am not able to get my drawrect functioning on 4.4 devices